# Is there a way to tell if a Cystoscape node is at a certain coordinates using Javascript?

Tags: javascript, cytoscape.js

I have an application where the user can create graphs using Cytoscape JS. To add a node the user clicks on the Cytoscape container and a node is added at the click position. Recently, I have added implemented my own snap-to-grid methods, and I am wondering if there is any way I can check if a node already exists at certain coordinates, as to not allow the user to create overlapping nodes. I've searched and searched through the Cytoscape JS documentation and haven't had any luck finding anything useful. Future thanks for any assistance

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you are using event listeners, you should implement them according to your goals. Clicking on nodes, edges or the canvas can all implement their own logic within the event listener ([cy.on()](https://js.cytoscape.org/#cy.on)):

```
// unbind click events first
cy.off('click');

// click event for nodes
cy.on('click', 'node', function(evt){
   ...
});

// click event for edges
cy.on('click', 'edge', function(evt){
   ...
});

// click event for the canvas
cy.on('tap', function(event){
  if( event.target === cy ){
    ...
  }
});
```

With this, you can add nodes to the canvas, skip adding them on nodes and edges or do some other stuff like an alert for the user with some information about why they should choose another location.

If you want to manually check if a location is empty, you can do it naively like this:

```
cy.nodes().each(function(node) {
    // yourPosition should be look like this: { x: x-pos, y: y-pos }
    // where x-/y-pos are the grid positions x and y coordinates
    if(node.position() == yourPosition) { 
        // do something 
    }
});
```

Comment: Hi Stephan. I have already implemented a bunch of event listeners to my cytoscape canvas. I am trying to create a snap-to-grid function, where when a user clicks the nearest point is calculated and then a node is created at this new point. But first I need to make sure there isn't already a node there as to avoid nodes from overlapping. I'm not sure on how to see if a node exists at a certain location.

Comment: There is no function for cytoscape.js where you can search for a node at a specific position, but you can do that yourself by iterating over every node and checking its position with the point you calculated. Is that what you want?

Comment: I edited my answer with a quick example, also, there was an issue about this feature, but that was closed some time ago: [link](https://github.com/cytoscape/cytoscape.js/issues/1209).

Comment: Is there any way to create a fake event or modify the current click event with the new coordinates? If so you could use if (event.target.isNode())

Comment: I don't know what you mean by fake events exactly, could you add some of your code (like the part with event.target.isNode()). Doesn't need to be working or anything, just some place to start.

Comment: The event.target is the part I'm not sure about. Maybe you could potentially invoke a click at the snap coordinates and if there is a node at the new click add a node at the previous click location. Thanks again for your help.